# How to make Axios make call for json response with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, axios

I read and found that axios will make the call for json format to an endpoint, which doesn't seem to be the case here. My endpoint looks like this:

```
  def create
    @form = Form.new(form_params)
    if @form.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(@form, notice: "Form created successfully") }
        format.json { render json: {message: "Form created successfully"} }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render 'new' }
        format.json { render json: {errors: @form.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end

    end
  end
```

My axios call looks like this:

```
function instance() {
  return axios.create({
    headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')},
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    responseType: 'json'
  });
}

function post(url, data={}) {
  return instance().post(url, data)
}
```

here is how I make the call:

```
post('/forms', {
          form: this.$data
        }).then((response) => {
          console.log("success");
          console.log(response.data);
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log("errro");
          console.log(error.response);
        })
    }
```

It works if change `/forms` to `/forms.json`, any tip on how to fix this?

Comment: any solution here? I think I've the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857964/csrf-invalidauthenticitytoken-with-rails-and-react

Comment: I checked your question and it is not related, but @Evolutio I've added a link that should help you.

Comment: Does it work for you if you add .json?

Comment: Nope. I think my problem is that I used a subdomain. I edit my thread.

Answer (score 11):

The correct header key should be Accept. So in reference to your question it should work with: `axios.create({headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}})`

---

Apart of that, it is worth considering to set axios's default headers in a suitable location, like this:

```
let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = token
axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, to solve the problem, I set "X-Requested-With" header key to **XMLHttpRequest**.

Example:

```js
const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = token;
axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

This may be work for you ;)!

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = authKey;
axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
```

**Now go for the axios method....header has been added like postman**