# CSRF InvalidAuthenticityToken with rails and react

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, axios

I can't get my code working with the CSRF-Token.

I have a axiosconfig file where I setup axios and export it:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://api.domain.tld/v1/',
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken
  }
});

export default instance
```

and my react component where I import it:

```
import axios from '../config/axios'
```

in my form on submit I fire this Post:

```
axios
  .post('/test', {
    longUrl: this.state.testValue
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

my head looks like this:
[image]

the request what axios is posting is this:
[image]

the CSRF-Tokens from the request-header and my head are the same but my rails-app respons with error 422 (Unprocessable Entity) and:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

is it possible that something with this is the problem:

```
  // `xsrfCookieName` is the name of the cookie to use as a value for xsrf token
  xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN', // default

  // `xsrfHeaderName` is the name of the http header that carries the xsrf token value
  xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN', // default
```

my /v1/test looks like this:

```
class Api::V1::IndexController < ApplicationController
  def test
    render :json => params
  end
end
```

Or is it something in my config/application.rb:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module TestAppForMe
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.1

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
        # resource '*',
        #   headers: ['Origin', 'Accept', 'Content-Type', 'X-CSRF-Token'],
        #   :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

in my routes I've something like this:

```
constraints subdomain: "api" do
    scope module: "api" do
      namespace :v1 do
        root 'index#index'
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: how does this token get generated?this error suggests token you are sending doesn't match what stores in server

Comment: I think you are doing it right. You should refer this thread for more details
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2734

Comment: @kasperite they got generated with '<%= csrf_meta_tags %>' in my application.html.erb.

Comment: @aks I browsed the thread you linked. And I got an idea. My react-app get working on http://my-domain.tld/ and it works. The request's are done to a other url: http://api.my-domain.tld/v1/test. I think there is a cookie mismatch or something.